# Find the linear transform matrix with respect to an ordered basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let u1=[3,1]^T, u2=[5,2]^T, v1=[1,-2]^T, v2=[1,-1]^T, and let L be a linear operator on R^2 whose matrix representation with respect to the ordered basis u1, u2 is A=[2 1;3 2] ([2,3]^T column 1 and [1,2]^T column 2). Find the matrix representing L with respect to the ordered basis {v1,v2}.

From what I understand, A is a transformation matrix such that A*u transforms u, where u is a coordinate vector in terms of u1 and u2. So am I being asked to find a transformation matrix that results in A*u if I multiply this matrix by the coordinate vector in terms of v1 and v2? I am very lost as to what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

So you know that linear transformation $A$ acts on your linear space as

$L: \vec u = u^1 \vec u_1 + u^2 \vec u_1 \mapsto A \vec u = (2u^1 + u^2) \vec u_1 + (3 u^1 + 2 u^2) \vec u_1.$

If you substitute expressions for $\vec u_1$ and $\vec u_2$ in terms of $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ to the above you'd get the expression of the form

$L: \vec u = v^1 \vec v_1 + v^2 \vec v_1 \mapsto A \vec u = (a_{11} v^1 + a_{12} v^2) \vec v_1 + (a_{21} v^1 + a_{22} v^2) \vec v_1.$

$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
$
would be your sought-for matrix for $L$ in $\{\vec v_1, \vec v_2\}$ basis.